# Combine toolbar and title bar in Qt

Tags: macos, qt, qt5

How can the toolbar be implemented in the top bar, like, for example, `Tiled` has it done?

[image: Tiled]
Normally, the toolbar looks like the follows:

[image]

Example code how it is currently:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr) {
        auto *tbar = new QToolBar();  
        tbar->addWidget(new QPushButton("Push Me"));
        this->addToolBar(tbar);
    }
};
```

Comment: Why don't you look at the source of Tiled?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are still using Qt 4.x, you can just use the `setUnifiedTitleAndToolBarOnMac(bool set)` function that is included in QMainWindow:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr) {
        auto *tbar = new QToolBar();  
        tbar->addWidget(new QPushButton("Push Me"));
        this->addToolBar(tbar);
        this->setUnifiedTitleAndToolBarOnMac(true); // activate Mac-style toolbar
    }
};
```

See also: https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html#unifiedTitleAndToolBarOnMac-prop

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers. A link can be a useful addition to an answer, but the answer should be readable without the link. In your case it would contain no information anymore.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Qt5, check out [QtMacExtras](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmacextras-index.html) 
(https://github.com/qt/qtmacextras)

You can give your QToolBar a native Mac look and feel using
    QtMacExtras::setNativeToolBar

Answer (score 1):

If you subclass QMainWindow and/or QToolBar and change the kind of frame they load/have, you may be able to get the effect you want.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qframe.html#details

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qframe

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-customizing.html#the-box-model

Another way to maybe achieve this result, but is kind of hacky, you could put another frameless widget of the right color over the part of the frames that are showing.  Using `Qt:Tool` and `Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint` and `Qt::FramelessWindowHint`, you should be able to get your coverup widget to hide the joint.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to remove the frame border using a stylesheet.

```
tbar->setStyleSheet("QToolBar { border: 0px }");
```