# Removing title bar from Qt application

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

[image]

I made an application using Qt Creator. Since I wanted it to look different from normal Windows applications, I removed the Windows title bar. However, without the title bar, I wasn't able to move, minimize and maximize the application. If possible, I want my application to be moved by holding the menu bar and put those three colorful round buttons which are used in OS X applications at the upper right corner of menu bar. Is this doable in Qt?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combine toolbar and title bar in Qt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16681965/combine-toolbar-and-title-bar-in-qt)

Comment: I don't think that its a duplicate of that. That question is for Mac and this one's for Windows from what I read.

Comment: @user3734823, are you talking about "Windows", "windows" or "window's"? I hope I did not edit that wrongly. You might want to add "on Windows" to the title if that is the case.

Comment: Yes, anything is doable in Qt.

You need to call `setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint)` on your window in order remove the title bar and then implement your own title bar widget on which you will need to add a QMenuBar and which you will put in the natural place of a title bar. Of course, you will have to implement all the mouse events, buttons(minimize/maximize/close) and style yourself. You will also loose the Aero effects and shadows which you will also need to implement yourself if you want them....

Answer (score 0):

I'll explain how to get the structure of it but I'll leave it to you to style everything and connect the signals.

The best thing would be to create your own `QWidget` class called something like 'TitleBar' and give it a `QHBoxLayout`. Within the 'TitleBar' class, create another `QWidget` and `QHBoxLayout` to contain the buttons. Create the 3 `QPushButtons` and add them to it. Next, you need to create your own `QMenuBar` class called something like 'MenuBar' so you can get the mouse events and build a drag mechanism. Below is some example code of how you might accomplish this.

TitleBar

```
TitleBar::TitleBar() :
    QWidget()
{

    QHBoxLayout *l = new QHBoxLayout();
    l->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    setLayout(l);

    QWidget *buttonGroup = new QWidget();
    QHBoxLayout *buttonLayout = new QHBoxLayout();
    buttonLayout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

    QPushButton *minButton = new QPushButton("");
    QPushButton *maxButton = new QPushButton("");
    QPushButton *closeButton = new QPushButton("");

    buttonLayout->addWidget(minButton, Qt::AlignRight);
    buttonLayout->addWidget(maxButton, Qt::AlignRight);
    buttonLayout->addWidget(closeButton, Qt::AlignRight);

    buttonGroup->setLayout(buttonLayout);
    buttonGroup->setFixedSize(buttonGroup->sizeHint());

    MenuBar *bar = new MenuBar();
    bar->addMenu("&File");

    l->addWidget(bar);
    l->addWidget(buttonGroup);

}
```

MenuBar

```
void MenuBar::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(event->buttons() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        QPointF newPos = (event->localPos() - dragPos) + window()->pos();
        window()->move(newPos.x(), newPos.y());
    }
    else
        QMenuBar::mouseMoveEvent(event);
}

void MenuBar::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    dragPos = event->localPos();
    QMenuBar::mousePressEvent(event);
}
```

You can then just add the 'TitleBar' class to your main layout of your widget with top alignment and you're all good! Now this isn't perfect but I think it gets the job done.

Here's an example project that uses this method: http://www.filedropper.com/menubartest

Comment: I tried as you suggested but keep getting this error msg, syntax error : mssing ; before identifier QtCoreModule

Comment: Oh btw, I used the promotion method to add the custom widget, and I included the custom menubar class in titlebar.h. Could the be the cause of problem?

Comment: I'm not sure. I posted an example project using this method in the answer. Just copy the menubar and titlebar classes to your project.

Comment: Is there a way to not use localpos? cuz my QT version doesn't support localpos() but globalpos()

Comment: Just use `pos()` then. You should consider upgrading to Qt5 though seriously